# How do I find element in object typescript code

Tags: typescript, react-native

So, am trying to assign colours to my icons dynamically ... but this line of code keeps complaining,

```
let icon = iconsList[name];
```

When I hover of it .. This is the explanation "

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ heart: string; star: string; like: string; dislike: string; flash: string; marker: string; filter: string; user: string; circle: string; hashtag: string; calendar: string; chevronLeft: string; optionsV: string; optionsH: string; chat: string; explore: string; }'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ heart: string; star: string; like: string; dislike: string; flash: string; marker: string; filter: string; user: string; circle: string; hashtag: string; calendar: string; chevronLeft: string; optionsV: string; optionsH: string; chat: string; explore: string; }'.ts(7053)

```js
interface Props{
    name:string,
}

const Icon = ({ name }:Props) => {
    const iconsList = {
      heart: '&#xe800;',
      star: '&#xe801;',
      like: '&#xe800;',
      dislike: '&#xe802;',
      flash: '&#xe803;',
      marker: '&#xf031;',
      filter: '&#xf0b0;',
      user: '&#xf061;',
      circle: '&#xf039;',
      hashtag: '&#xf029;',
      calendar: '&#xf4c5;',
      chevronLeft: '&#xf004;',
      optionsV: '&#xf142;',
      optionsH: '&#xf141;',
      chat: '&#xf4ac;',
      explore: '&#xf50d;'
    };
  
    let icon = iconsList[name];
    icon = icon.substr(3);
    icon = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(icon, 16));
  
    return icon;
  };
  
  export default Icon;
```

ScreenShot of the code in Vscode [On line 25, am trying to pick the specific icon color but it complains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI0dy.png)

Comment: which error code do you get?

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth breaking this down a little bit because it's quite educational. Getting a property `string` from an `object` is something of a partial function; some combinations of properties and objects can return values, but not all.

In your example, getting a property which has type `string` (`name`) from the type of `iconsList` is not guaranteed to give a value; what if the `string` is `"xyz"`? What *ought* the value be in that case? It's hard to give a really concrete answer to that.

If we look at a condensed example, we see the same error:

```js
const getIcon = (iconName: string) => {
  const iconsList = {
      heart: '&#xe800;',
      star: '&#xe801;',
  };

  return iconsList[iconName];
};
```

Gives us the same error on the line `return iconsList[iconName];`

We can do better though, in order to make this work. If what we want to say is that the `iconName` we pass in will always be a property of the `iconsList` object, we can do that via. a type:

```js
const iconsList = {
    heart: '&#xe800;',
    star: '&#xe801;',
};

const getIcon = (iconName: keyof typeof iconsList) => {
  return iconsList[iconName];
}

const x = getIcon('heart'); // works
const y = getIcon('xyz');   // type error
```

...and we can get more generic with this:

```js
const path = <T>(o: T) => (k: keyof T) => o[k];

const iconsList = {
    heart: '&#xe800;',
    star: '&#xe801;',
};

const getIcon = path(iconsList);

const x = getIcon('heart'); // works
const y = getIcon('xyz');   // type error
```

If you'd like to always return a usable value no matter what the input, consider looking into a [`Maybe`](https://blog.bitsrc.io/get-better-type-checking-in-javascript-with-the-maybe-type-e7f70b23b505) return type; that way, you can always return a `Maybe`, which will be a `Nothing` if you can't get the key on the object.

Hopefully that gives an insight into why you're getting the error and how you can fix it. If you have any questions, please ask away.

---

Update as per comment:

You'd want to make sure that you're also setting the type in `Props` in order that we can use it to access `iconTypes`:

```js
const iconsList = {
    heart: '&#xe800;',
    star: '&#xe801;',
    like: '&#xe800;',
    dislike: '&#xe802;',
    flash: '&#xe803;',
    marker: '&#xf031;',
    filter: '&#xf0b0;',
    user: '&#xf061;',
    circle: '&#xf039;',
    hashtag: '&#xf029;',
    calendar: '&#xf4c5;',
    chevronLeft: '&#xf004;',
    optionsV: '&#xf142;',
    optionsH: '&#xf141;',
    chat: '&#xf4ac;',
    explore: '&#xf50d;'
};

interface Props{
    name: keyof typeof iconsList;
}

etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and doesn't work unfortunately. But I love the way you are approaching this: what am trying to achieve is ..                                      import Icon from './Icon';    <Icon name="heart" />

Comment: Glad to hear that you liked it; may I ask what went wrong? Perhaps you have an error, in which case I imagine we can solve it fairly easily

Comment: Am getting an error " Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"heart" | "star"'. " ...

Comment: Ah ok - it sounds like you need to be more specific in your type in `Props`; I'll update my answer

Comment: @FeniHerbert that's updated now, hopefully that will solve it

Comment: I get an error of "JSX element type 'string' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. " when am <Icon name="heart" /> ....it's now this complaining <Icon name="heart" />

Comment: @OliverRadini, curious how you'd answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62070437/633183)...

Comment: @Thankyou I'm glad you liked it, that's always good to hear. I'll take a look at the question you mention; thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @FeniHerbert Ah ok - I think this is unrelated to the issue you've been having with this thus far; are you able to post the problem in a separate question and link me to it?

Comment: @OliverRadini .. I here is the link to the question [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075694/jsx-element-type-string-is-not-a-constructor-function-for-jsx-elements-typesc)

Answer (score 0):

You can make [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)  for this type of object

```js
type KeyValues = {
  [index: string]: string
}

const iconsList: KeyValues = {
   ...values...
}
```

Comment: By doing it this way we lose the ability to verify whether `iconsList[name]` exists

Comment: The author didn't specify such case. Again this is not codereview stack exchange

Comment: Though it wasn't specified by the author, I think it's still a relevant point; if we want to just find ways of removing all type checking from typescript, then perhaps we'd be better off using javascript

Answer (score 0):

So according to OliverRadini this how you can implement it if am following him in the correct way.

Icon.ts file

```
const iconsList = {
    heart: '&#xe800;',
    star: '&#xe801;',
    like: '&#xe800;',
    dislike: '&#xe802;',
    flash: '&#xe803;',
    marker: '&#xf031;',
    filter: '&#xf0b0;',
    user: '&#xf061;',
    circle: '&#xf039;',
    hashtag: '&#xf029;',
    calendar: '&#xf4c5;',
    chevronLeft: '&#xf004;',
    optionsV: '&#xf142;',
    optionsH: '&#xf141;',
    chat: '&#xf4ac;',
    explore: '&#xf50d;'
};

interface Props{
    name: keyof typeof iconsList;
}

const Icon = ({ name }:Props) => {
    const path = <T>(o: T) => (k: keyof T) => o[k];

    const getIcon = path(iconsList);
    const x = getIcon(name); // works
    return x;
 };

export default Icon;
```

Then how to reuse the icon on the

test.tsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from './Icon';

interface Props {
}

const TestComponent = ({}: Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerTest}>
      <View style={styles.testView}>
        <Text style={styles.testText}>
          <Icon name="heart" /> Test icon
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: Yeah, something like this , if not similar .. but this still brings an  error