# How to write types / or use use types for flatten object key in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this scenario

```js
interface abc {
  a: { b: string }
}

const test: abc = { a: { b: 'string'} }

test['a.b'] = 'new string' // error type a.b doesnt exists
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-night-9u5ps?file=/src/index.ts

How to solve this error? How can I utilize the already defined type and still use the flatten key?

PS: I cannot use it like test.a.b

Comment: How are you flattening this object? Also the sandbox you linked does not have your code.

Comment: import { [fromNullable](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#fromnullable), [chain](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#chain), [getOrElse](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#getorelse) } from "[fp-ts/lib/Option](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html)"

Comment: I am manually doing it, as i require for only one key. Updated the link

Answer (score 1):

What we'd like to see Typescript do here is convert one set of keys to another. There are ways it can do that, for instance with `Pick`:

```js
interface IA {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

const x: Pick<IA, 'a' | 'b'> = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3, // type error here as we're not picking that property
}
```

In this example, Typescript is able to convert between the set of keys `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `['a', 'b']` based on selecting certain specified keys. We can also extend an object's keys:

```js
type TestExtentionType = IA & { d: number };

const y: TestExtentionType = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: true,
    d: 4,
}
```

What we'd need the type system to do though, in order to have typescript determine automatically the return types you're looking for, is to be able to go from `key, key` to `'key.key'`, or more generically, we need Typescript's type system to be able to concatenate string literals. At the point at which I'm writing this, [it doesn't seem to be possible to have typescript do that.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754)

The only option I can see to get close to what you need would be to define a specific type with your flattened key:

```js
interface abc {
  a: { b: string }
}

interface abcFlattened {
    'a.b': string;
}

const flattenAbc = (x: abc): abcFlattened =>
    // do the flattening
```

Other options involve complete rewrites of what you're doing; if you want to get at that key as 'a.b' then I don't know as there's any other way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you think there is a workaround for this ?

Comment: I'm just trying to edit something useful into the answer ha

Comment: @heypran Wish I could say I had some better options for you, if you're interested in some complete rewrites I could give some examples

Comment: Thank you, I cannot do a rewrite atm. :)