# JSX element type 'string' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So i have been working on a reusable icon element that I can call in any class and just pass a string `<Icon name="chat" />` that contain the specific colour of the icon .. This error is the result of the previous question I raised .. you can find the link below

[I raised a question early before this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068664/how-do-i-find-element-in-object-typescript-code)

*icon.ts file*

```
const iconsList = {
    heart: '&#xe800;',
    star: '&#xe801;',
    like: '&#xe800;',
    dislike: '&#xe802;',
    flash: '&#xe803;',
    marker: '&#xf031;',
    filter: '&#xf0b0;',
    user: '&#xf061;',
    circle: '&#xf039;',
    hashtag: '&#xf029;',
    calendar: '&#xf4c5;',
    chevronLeft: '&#xf004;',
    optionsV: '&#xf142;',
    optionsH: '&#xf141;',
    chat: '&#xf4ac;',
    explore: '&#xf50d;'
};

interface Props{
    name: keyof typeof iconsList;
}

const Icon = ({name }: Props) => {
    let icon = iconsList[name];
    icon = icon.substr(3);
    icon = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(icon, 16));

    return icon;
 };

export default Icon;
```

*profile.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../assets/styles';

import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from '../components/Icon';
const Profile = () => {
return (

<TouchableOpacity>
  <Text style={styles.topIconLeft}>
    <Icon name="chevronLeft" />
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

);
}
```

This line of `<Icon name="chevronLeft" />`complains with an error of "JSX element type 'string' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.ts(2605)

Screenshot : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is not a valid return value for a react component. A react component always has to return a `ReactDOM` element or a `Fragment`, that implements the `render` method. You can try

```
const Icon : React.SFC<Props> = ({name }: Props) => {
    let icon = iconsList[name];
    icon = icon.substr(3);
    icon = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(icon, 16));

    return <>{icon}</>;
 };
```

And actually it won't hurt if you renamed `icon.ts` to `icon.tsx`. Depending on your compiler settings the `<>{icon}</>` part might not get recognized correctly as JSX markup.

Comment: No change , still the same error .. plus Unterminated regular expression literal. warning. Btw am building a react-native app

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the `React.SFC` part. Try now!

Comment: ok, the issue seems to disappear, but then a new issue is introduced "Type '({ name }: any) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'SFC<Props>'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'."

Comment: Well, the way you define your props seems a little cheesy. Why won’t you just go with `interface Props : { name : string }` for a start. Because `keyof typeof iconsList` is realy just a logical expression that returns boolean. Look up the `typeof` in JS/TS docs.

Comment: If you realy realy wish to check the values of `iconsList` at compile time you should convert it to an `enum`.

Comment: @px1mp I disagree - what's the problem with ensuring that the icon is one of a specified type? What's the practical different between a type of `keyof` and an enum? `keyof` boils down to an enum of the keys

Comment: @px1mp we're not talking about runtime checks at all; `typeof` is a compile time check here because it's in a type definition

Comment: @OliverRadini - well then why doesn’t work the way you suggest ?

Comment: @px1mp I'm away from my pc at the moment - if you'd like to put together a minimal example in the typescript playground you'll see that it works as expected. I don't mean to come in and disagree but when you're saying previous answers are misleading, I think it's fair to expect you to back up precisely what it is that you think will not work; it'd be best to make your criticisms on those previous answers in a way that is clear and verifiable

Comment: @OliverRadini - very well, I see it now. To use `keyof typeof` you need the underlying type be an `enum` anyway (some struct might posibly work as well). You are talking about *type definition* but in you examples are passing it an anonymous object, which I hope we both agree is not a `type`.

Comment: @px1mp I don't see where I'm passing an anonymous object; the functions are written to handle generics, or to work on the typeof a value, which is a type?

Comment: @OliverRadini - sorry Oliver, you were right, `typeof keyof` works the way you proposed. And the issue with my answer was, that the last line should read `return <>{icon}</>` not just `return <>icon</>`.

Comment: @px1mp that's good news, glad that's all cleared up and and working